# LOGITECH/LUA SCRIPT: IsModifierPressed for spacebar

Tags: lua, logitech, logitech-gaming-software

I'm trying to write a script where checks whether my spacebar is pressed or not. When I'm looking at LUA api for logitech, I'm seeing "IsModifierPressed" but that's only for control,shift,alt, not spacebar. Is there anything that I can do for spacebar? thnx

Comment: space is not a modifier key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LGS/GHUB is unable to monitor press/release of usual keys (letters, digits, spacebar) on your keyboard.
Such feature would make possible to write a keylogger script in Lua, and Logitech wants to prevent this to make script sharing safe.